# how to use priority queue in rabbitmq?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, priority-queue

rabbitmq version 3.6.1
I don't kown how to create a priority queue in rabbitmq with erlang code.

My code is below :

```
{ok, Connection} =
    amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{host = "localhost"}),
{ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),

amqp_channel:call(Channel,
                  #'queue.declare'{queue = <<"my-priority-queue">>, passive = true,
                                   arguments = [{<<"x-max-priority">>, 10}]}).
```

Comment: An exception occured when ran  these code, It said

**exception exit : {shutdown, 
                                 {gen_server, call,
                                     [<0.56.0>,
                                       {call, 
                                             {'queue.declare', 0, <<"my-priority-queue">>,
   ture, false, false, false, false, [{<<"x-max-priority">>, 10}]}, non, <0.33.0>
} ..........
]}}

Answer (score 0):

`argumnets` are AMQP type table and its entries have to have a type specified in Erlang API. Try

```
arguments = [{<<"x-max-priority">>, long, 10}]
```

Other handy types are `longstr`, `timestamp`, `array` (`[{Type, Value}]`), `table` (`[{Key, Type, value}]`) and so on.